# pandas: future datetimes(random deidentification) is unable to be parsed, returns NaT

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

My data has been deidentified, and has years set randomly to the future.  I think that is what is messing up pandas read_csv() and to_datetime, can only see it as NaT.

1. playing with read_csv(): date_parser and infer_datetime_format not fruitful.
2. read_csv without time index, and then converting to_datetime, not helpful either.

setting my own parse function in read_csv:
`

```
 #2943-02-28 00:00:00
 #%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
 tparse = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') #,coerce=True)
 mc_data = pd.read_csv("./data/healthdata.csv",encoding='utf-8',names=hdr,sep='\t',skiprows=1, index_col='realtime', parse_dates=['realtime'], dayfirst=False,keep_date_col=True, verbose=True, nrows=2000, infer_datetime_format=True, date_parser=tparse )
```

`

bypass read_csv and apply to_datetime after:
`

```
  mc_data = pd.read_csv("./data/healthdata.csv", names=hdr, skiprows=1, nrows=2000)
  mc_data['realtime'] = mc_data['realtime'].apply(tparse) 
  print mc_data.realtime.apply(type)
```

`

outputs:

```
0     <class 'pandas.tslib.NaTType'>
1     <class 'pandas.tslib.NaTType'>
2     <class 'pandas.tslib.NaTType'>
```

I think the problem is the dates are set in the future, and that is causing problems.  Has anyone had this problem, is there a better encoding?

This problem cropped up with upgrade from 0.10 to 0.14.

-thanks

---edit----
The values for each subject ranges(randomly) for hundreds of years in the future.  On my small subset, the range is 300 years, and some values differ by seconds...  Therefore something like this: `galactica = pd.period_range('2900-01-01', '3200-01-01', freq='D')`
is huge compared to actual number of rows (again this is just a small subset, when I run it over the complete dataset its going to be totally unfeasible)

Or, doing something like `mc_data = mc_data.to_period(freq="min")` throws errors.

I guess I can try to just subtract all the dates by 1000 years, but is there a better way?

-thanks

Comment: Can you paste here the first few rows/or a pretend csv which demonstrate this?

Comment: if your dates are out of oandas range, use periods, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#timestamp-limitations

Comment: And if you want them outside of the index, you'll probably need to use integer timestamps :/